# Consumer/Producer with order and constraint on consumed items

Tags: c#-4.0, concurrency, task-parallel-library, concurrent-programming

I have the following scenario

- I am writing a server that process files (jobs)

  - a file has a "prefix" and a time
  - the files should be processed according to time (older file first) but also take into account the prefix (files with same prefix can't be processed concurrently)
- I have a thread (Task with Timer) that watches over a directory and adds files to a "queue" (producer)
- I have several consumers that take the file from "queue" (consumer) - they should conform to the above rules.

  - the job of each task is kept in some list (this indicates the constraints)
- There are several consumers, the number of consumers is determined at startup.

One of the requirement is to be able to gracefully stop the consumers (either immediately or let ongoing processes to finish).

I did something along this line:

```
while (processing)
{
    //limits number of concurrent tasks
    _processingSemaphore.Wait(queueCancellationToken);  
    //Take next job when available or wait for cancel signal
    currentwork = workQueue.Take(taskCancellationToken);

    //check that it can actually process this work
    if (CanProcess(currnetWork)
    { 
        var task = CreateTask(currentwork)
        task.ContinueWith((t) => { //release processing slot });
    }
    else
       //release slot, return job? something else?
 }
```

The cancellation tokens sources are in the caller code and can be cancelled. There are two in order to be able to stop queuing while not cancelling running tasks.

I tired to implement the "queue" as BlockingCollection wrapping a "safe" SortedSet. The general idea work (ordering by time) except the case in which I need to find a new job that matches the constraint. If I return the job to the queue and try to take again I will get the same one.

It is possible to take jobs from the queue until I find a proper one and then returning the "illegal" jobs back but this may cause issues with other consumers processing out of order jobs

Another alternative is to pass a simple collection and a way to lock it and just lock and do a simple search according to current constraints. Again, this means writing code that will possibly not be thread-safe.

Any other suggestion / pointers / data structures that can help?

Comment: The earliest such a job could be processed is when the first one was finished.  So the worker may as well process the next one.  So put list of jobs in the queue, not just jobs, where every job in a list has the same prefix.

Comment: @HansPassant - I thought about it - have some per-process local queue but not sure this is not 100% correct - having the same consumer queue the next job with same prefix may violate the processing-by-time requirement - I need to think this through though and see if it works with all the constraints. In any case- thanks for the input.

Comment: @HansPassant - what you pointed out is indeed correct. I ended up implementing a local queue in each "specialized" consumer and queue additional jobs "locally" on their queues are required. In case the consumer "missed" the queued file (e.g. the job was added between the time it was done after the consumer exist is processing loop) it is returned to the general queue and processed by whatever available consumer. Can I mark comment as answer?

Comment: @TomerCagan please see my edited [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13877533/1514235). Hope it helps to simplify your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would have implemented your requirement(s) with [TPL Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603.aspx). Look at the way you could implement the [Producer-Consumer pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228601.aspx) with it. I believe this will meet all the requirements you have (including cancellation on the consumers).

**EDIT (for those that do not like to read documentation, but who does...)**

Here is an example of how you could implement the requirements with [TPL Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603.aspx). The beauty of this implementation is that consumers are not bound to a single thread and only uses a pool thread when it needs to process data.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BufferBlock<string> source = new BufferBlock<string>();
        var cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
        LinkConsumer(source, "A", cancellation.Token);
        LinkConsumer(source, "B", cancellation.Token);
        LinkConsumer(source, "C", cancellation.Token);

        // Link an action that will process source values that are not processed by other 
        source.LinkTo(new ActionBlock<string>((s) => Console.WriteLine("Default action")));

        while (cancellation.IsCancellationRequested == false)
        {
            ConsoleKey key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;
            switch (key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.Escape:
                    cancellation.Cancel();
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Posted value {0} on thread {1}.", key, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                    source.Post(key.ToString());
                    break;
            }
        }

        source.Complete();
        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void LinkConsumer(ISourceBlock<string> source, string prefix, CancellationToken token)
    {
        // Link a consumer that will buffer and process all input of the specified prefix
        var consumer = new ActionBlock<string>(new Action<string>(Process), new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1, SingleProducerConstrained = true, CancellationToken = token, TaskScheduler = TaskScheduler.Default });
        var linkDisposable = source.LinkTo(consumer, (p) => p == prefix);

        // Dispose the link (remove the link) when cancellation is requested.
        token.Register(linkDisposable.Dispose);
    }

    private static void Process(string arg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Processed value {0} in thread {1}", arg, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        // Simulate work
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't explain how to solve the problem in question in any way.

Comment: @svick At the end of the question was asked "Any other suggestion / pointers / data structures that can help?" and that is exactly what I gave him. Using Dataflow *will* meet the requirements, but that is only if you bother reading the documentation links I provided. In my opinion answers should not spoonfeed nor re-document anything, but only provide guidens or solve undocumented problems.

Comment: But TPL Dataflow doesn't contain anything that will directly solve the problem in question. This is not a simple producer-consumer scenario, so your links alone won't be very helpful.

Comment: @svick actually it does solve the problem (and more efficiently at that). Sorry for the late response, but I do not like to work over the holidays. Please see my edit.

Comment: But if you do it like this and have something like `aaaaab`, then the `b` won't be processed while the first four `a`s are being processed, so it can be very ineffective. That's why I was saying “use TPL Dataflow” is not very helpful: it doesn't say how exactly should you use it. And answering that is not trivial.

Comment: @svick as far as the question goes it is assumed that a fixed prefix is given to each file, thus each prefix is processed by its own pipe (each pipe runs concurrently; on its own pool thread). And if you actually run the example you will see that, If you have a case of `aaaab`, the first 4 `a`s will be processed concurrently with `b` (the `a`s will be processed in order as it is processed on the same pipe, exactly as the question requested).

Comment: You're right, I was wrong, it will work correctly. For some reason, I was assuming your consumers had `BoundedCapacity` set, I'm not sure why.

Comment: Interesting approach and good example. Thinking a little "out-of-the-box" (or, out of my box ;-). It seems to answer the requirement (though I need more time to digest).

Answer (score 0):

I think Hans is right: if you already have a thread-safe SortedSet (that implements `IProducerConsumerCollection`, so it can be used in `BlockingCollection`), then all you need is to put only files that can be processed right now into the collection. If you finish a file which makes another file available for processing, add the other file to the collection at this point, not earlier.